# Is there a way to do something similar to col-md and col-sm but instead do it with height

Tags: html, css, sass, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I want for the height to change if a person is using a a small or large device similar to how sm md and lg work. Im creating a login form and it looks good on cell phones but when I try and view it on an ipad the form's height is to tall and the input text is spaced out too much.  There are large gaps in between each input.

This is where my form starts

```
<form [formGroup] = "signupForm" (ngSubmit)="OnSubmit()" class="col-7 col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-lg-4" style="border:3px solid red;width:70vw;height:85vh;">
```

Comment: what if you use height:auto with the bootstrap col classes?

Comment: Not quite sure if I understand it right, but I would use media queries for that.  Same as in bootstrap. Please have a look into source scss files.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
height:85vh
```

do:

```
height: 85vw;
```

[Further reading](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)

Plus, your inline style:

```
width:70vw;
```

may interfere bootstrap grid